# jQuery tabs open and scroll

Tags: jquery, tabs, responsive-design

I am using jqueryResponsiveTabs on my site below to create tabs that become an accordion at a certain viewpoint.

On the link below there is a tabbed area that on mobile becomes accordian. The personalise button at the top should open the 'personalise' tab in the 'what you need to know' section and also scroll the page down to this area.

I can get it to open the tab but I can't get it to scroll down.

Any thoughts?

http://www.swimmingcover.co.uk/bag/test.html

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
<title>Tangible Simple - Heart Trinket</title>

<link href="http://www.swimmingcover.co.uk/bag/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="http://www.swimmingcover.co.uk/bag/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="http://www.swimmingcover.co.uk/bag/css/global.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="http://www.swimmingcover.co.uk/bag/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.swimmingcover.co.uk/bag/css/frame.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.swimmingcover.co.uk/bag/css/navigation.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.swimmingcover.co.uk/bag/css/product.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.swimmingcover.co.uk/bag/css/style.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.swimmingcover.co.uk/bag/css/animation.css" />

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.swimmingcover.co.uk/bag/js/modernizr.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.swimmingcover.co.uk/bag/js/responsive.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.swimmingcover.co.uk/bag/js/jquery.mmenu.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.swimmingcover.co.uk/bag/js/jquery.responsiveTabs.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://www.swimmingcover.co.uk/bag/js/jquery.bxslider.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.swimmingcover.co.uk/bag/js/charCount.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>

<body id="product" class="tangible">

    <main id="content" class="container">
        <!--Breadcrumb Menu-->
        <nav class="fw_col" id="breadcrumb">
            <a title="Home" href="/">Home</a>
            <span class="pipe">›</span>
            <a title="Afternoon Tea" href="">Gifts</a>   
        </nav>

        <div class="fw_col">
            <div id="col_prd_fw">
                <h1 class="product_title fontgeomedium">Personalised Heart Trinket Box</h1>
                <span class="product_code">Product code: 10225745</span>
                <div class="top_review_summary mobile">
                    <span class="star_rating"><img src="images/product/reviews_star.png" width="64" height="14" alt="5 out of 5" /></span>
                    <span class="star_count">4.2 out of 5 (based on 263 reviews)</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="col_prd_lft">
                <div id="prd_img_area">
                    <img src="images/product_images/test.jpg" alt="Product Title" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="col_prd_rgt">
                <h1 class="product_title fontgeomedium">Test Product</h1>
                <span class="product_code">Product code: xxxxxxxx</span>
                <div class="top_review_summary">
                    <span class="star_rating"><img src="images/product/reviews_star.png" width="64" height="14" alt="5 out of 5" /></span>
                    <span class="star_count">4.2 out of 5 (based on 263 reviews)</span>
                </div>
                <div id="short_desc">
                    Test product
                </div>
                <ul id="prd_overview">
                    <li>Overview bullet</li>
                    <li>Overview bullet</li>
                    <li>Overview bullet</li>
                    <li>Overview bullet</li>
                </ul>
                <div id="price_area">
                    <span class="current_price"><span class="current_price_prefix">just</span> &pound;<span class="current_price_amount">xx</span></span>
                    <span class="previous_price">was &pound;xx</span>
                </div>
                <a class="button personalise tab-link" id="prd_page" href="#tab-2"><span>Personalise</span></a>
                <ul id="prd_overview" class="mobile">
                    <li>Overview bullet</li>
                    <li>Overview bullet</li>
                    <li>Overview bullet</li>
                    <li>Overview bullet</li>
                </ul>                
            </div>


            <div id="prd_tabbed_area" class="product_area" style="padding-top:250px;">
                <h3 class="fontgeomedium">What you need to know</h3>
                <div class="prd_tabbed_area_inner">
                    <div id="product_tabs">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#tab-1">About <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i><i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i><i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#tab-2">Personalise <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i><i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></i><i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#tab-3">Fine Print <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i><i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></i><i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#tab-4">Delivery <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i><i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i><i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i></a></li>
                        </ul>

                        <div id="tab-1" class="about_content">
                            <p>
                                  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer 
                                  took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially 
                                  unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages,
                            </p>
                        </div>

                        <div id="tab-2" class="personalise_content">
                            <div id="tangible_personalisation">
                                <h4 class="personalise_prd_ttl">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting:</h4>
                                <span class="personalise_intro">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting:</span>
                                <form>
                                    <span class="form_row">
                                    <label>Line one* </label>
                                    <input type="text" id="message1" placeholder="(e.g. Happy Birthday)" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = '(e.g. Happy Birthday)'" class="form-control" />
                                    </span>  
                                    <span class="form_row">                                                                                          
                                    <label>Line two* </label>
                                    <input type="text" id="message1" placeholder="(e.g. Happy Birthday2)" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = '(e.g. Happy Birthday2)'" class="form-control" />
                                    </span>

                                    <span class="form_row">                                                                                           
                                    <label>Line three* </label>
                                    <input type="text" id="message1" placeholder="(e.g. Happy Birthday3)" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = '(e.g. Happy Birthday3)'" class="form-control" />
                                    </span>                                                           
                                </form>

                                <span class="required_text">Fields marked with an * are required and must be completed</span>

                                <a class="button buynow tab-link" id="prd_page" href="#personalise_area"><span>BUY NOW</span></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div id="tab-3" class="fineprint_content">
                            <p>
                                 Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer 
                                  took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially 
                                  unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages,
                             </p>
                        </div>
                        <div id="tab-4" class="delivery_content">
                            <div id="delivery_table">
                                <div id="table_del_header">
                                    <span class="del_type">Delivery Type</span>
                                    <span class="del_time">Delivery Time</span>
                                    <span class="del_price">Price</span>
                                </div>
                                <div id="table_del_row">
                                    <span class="del_type">
                                        <span class="delivery_title"><i class="icon-truck"></i>Standard UK Delivery</span>
                                        <span class="delivery_details">(Please allow 4 to 7 working days for delivery. An exact delivery date cannot be guaranteed.)</span>
                                    </span>
                                    <span class="del_time">4-7 working days</span>
                                    <span class="del_price">&pound;3.76</span>
                                </div>
                                <div id="table_del_row">
                                    <span class="del_type">
                                        <span class="delivery_title"><i class="icon-truck"></i>Express UK Delivery</span>
                                        <span class="delivery_details">
                                            (Please allow up to 2 working days for this product to arrive. Due to the personalised nature of this product a specific delivery date cannot be guaranteed. )
                                        </span>
                                    </span>
                                    <span class="del_time">1-2 working days</span>
                                    <span class="del_price">&pound;8.50</span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>                        
                    </div>
                    <span class="prd_lower_cta">
                        <a href="">
                            <span class="prd_ttl fontgeomedium">Test Product - <span class="prd_price">&pound;xx</span></span>
                            <span class="button personalise" id="prd_page_cta" href="#"><span>Personalise</span></span>
                        </a>
                    </span>                    
                </div>
            </div> 

            <div id="prd_reviews">
                <h3 class="fontgeomedium">Customer Reviews <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></h3>
                <div class="reviews_summary">
                    <span class="star_rating"><img src="images/product/reviews_star.png" width="64" height="14" alt="5 out of 5" /></span>
                    <span class="star_count">4.2 out of 5</span>
                    <span class="star_recommended">173 out of 203 (85%) reviewers would recommend this product to a friend.</span>
                </div>
                <div class="reviews_actions">
                    <span class="review_write"><a href="">Write a review &#187;</a></span>
                    <span class="review_order">
                        <span>Choose a sort order</span>
                        <select>
                        <option value="Choose A Sort Order">Choose A Sort Order</option>
                        <option value="Rating High to Low">Rating High to Low</option>
                        <option value="Featured Reviews First">Featured Reviews First</option>
                        </select>
                    </span>
                </div>
                <div class="reviews_hidden_area">
                    hidden review area
                </div>
            </div>  
        </div>
    </main>



    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#product_tabs').responsiveTabs({
                rotate: false,
                //startCollapsed: 'accordion',
                collapsible: 'accordion',
                setHash: true,
                //disabled: [3],
                active: 0
            });
        });
    </script>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you please post some of your code?

Comment: I've added my code above - thanks

Comment: When I click the personalize button, it scrolls down, but it doesn't open a tab. You said "I can get it to open the tab but I can't get it to scroll down." Did you mean the other way around?

Comment: No, mine definitely opens the tab but doesn't scroll down

Comment: Oh, I see now. I think it was because I was on the page http://www.swimmingcover.co.uk/bag/test.html#tab-2 When it is like that, when you click the personalize button, it scrolls down, but the tab has already been opened.

Comment: I see the problem now, give me a second and I'll post an answer to remedy it.

Comment: Yup, I just need it to open the tab and scroll down to the area when the personalise button is clicked

Answer (score 0):

Change your jQuery script from:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#product_tabs').responsiveTabs({
            rotate: false,
            //startCollapsed: 'accordion',
            collapsible: 'accordion',
            setHash: true,
            //disabled: [3],
            active: 0
        });
    });
</script>
```

To:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#product_tabs').responsiveTabs({
            rotate: false,
            //startCollapsed: 'accordion',
            collapsible: 'accordion',
            setHash: true,
            //disabled: [3],
            active: 0,
            activate: function(event, tab){
                window.scrollTo(tab.id.getBoundingClientRect());
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks blubberguy22 - I'm not entirely sure what I need to change in my code though?

Comment: Where in your code are you changing the active tab?

Comment: When a tab is clicked the URL is appended with a #tabnumber depending on what tab was clicked

Comment: Ok, is there a way with JavaScript to open and close the tabs without appending the URL?

Comment: You could also just leave it the way it is and add the `window.scrollTo(document.getElementById('targetTab').getBoundingClientRect());` into the tabs and have it happen if the tab is open or it is the current appended tab.

Comment: Where would I add that in to though?

Comment: I have edited my answer to show what should be changed. I have looked into responsive-tabs and I realize that this functionality is built in already (sort-of, it doesn't auto-scroll, but script can be run when different tabs are selected).

Comment: Hmmm, this doesn't seem to have worked - I've added the new script but it still just opens the tab but stays at the top of the page

Comment: Add `console.log("Tab " + tab + " has activated");` right before the `window.scrollTo(tab.id.getBoundingClientRect());` to make sure the method is indeed being called. If it is, then the window scrolling function is probably incorrect.